# cx_Freeze: cannot find file/directory icon.gif

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am using cx_Freeze with Python 3.4.1 and I am trying to create an application from one of my Python programs. Unfortunately, I get this error after running the setup.py build:

```
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named icon.gif
```

Here is my setup file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32" : base = "Win32GUI"

opts = {"include_files": ['icon.gif', "EndingsPerfect.txt", "EndingsPPP.txt", "LatinEnglishPronouns.txt", "1stConj/", "2ndConj/", "3rdConj/", "4thConj/"], "includes": ["re"]}

setup(name = "LT",
      version = "1.0",
      description = "Latin verbs",
      author = "Laurence vS",
      options = {"build_exe": opts},
      executables = [Executable("latintranslatewithguipyw.pyw", base = base)])
```

This error confuses me since the `icon.gif` file is in the same folder as the setup file.

Here is the full traceback:

```
C:\Users\Laurence> python "C:\Users\Laurence\Dropbox\Python programs\GUIs\latintr
anslatewithgui\setup.py" build

running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Laurence\Dropbox\Python programs\GUIs\latintranslatewithgui\set
up.py", line 14, in <module>
    executables = [Executable("latintranslatewithguipyw.pyw", base = base)])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 362, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 231, in run
    metadata = metadata)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 108, in __init
__
    self._VerifyConfiguration()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 498, in _Verif
yConfiguration
    sourceFileName)
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named icon.gif
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's looking based on where you are when you run it. Use `cd` in the terminal to change to the directory where the files are, and then run `python setup.py build`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

Relative path names are found relative to where you run from, not where the the setup.py script is. Use `cd` in the terminal to change to the directory where setup.py is, and then run `python setup.py build`.

If that's not practical for some reason, you could use `os.chdir()` inside the setup.py script.